# Tracking subdomain with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have been tracking both the main site and the subdomain using the main site's code, however, when I go to Site Content > Pages, it links to the main domain when it's supposed to link to the subdomain for viewed pages that are supposed to refer to the subdomain.

This is the code I have:

Main site:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sitename.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Subdomain:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sub.sitename.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

I have read Google Analytics' documentation on the subdomain. For `_setDomainName` I have tried both `.sitename.com` and `sitename.com`, but it still shows the same results. So, the page content in the Google Analytics dashboard links to the main site, but it won't link to the subdomain when referring to subdomain pages.

This poses a problem for index pages because how will I know the division of unique views between the domain and subdomain? I must be doing something wrong here!

Comment: I am having same problem. One solution/workaround is a rewrite in an .htaccess to index.html for all requests :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167755/append-index-html-to-root-directory

however this is NOT ideal and works for me only because my main domain is index.php and other index.html.

Another interesting thing is in Google Analytics you can click Page Title tab (i.e. not the Page tab) and then you have it differentiated. Again, only if you have a different Page Title on the subdomain page!

Comment: See too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033218/google-analytics-api-tracking-subdomains

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting up separate profiles for your subdomains? Example:

**profile 1:** rollup that has no filters, takes everything, so that you can see data from everywhere

**profile 2:** only traffic for www.sitename.com.  Create a filter to include only www.sitename.com traffic.

**profile 3:** only traffic for sub.sitename.com.  Create a filter to include only sub.sitename.com traffic.

Comment: I do have separate profiles for my subdomains. I wanted it all combined. I cannot believe something so simple like this is a problem with Google Analytics. You'd think they could include the child domain with page content and whatnot!

Comment: how about a filter to rewrite the page name to include the domain?